# Why does my python script work differently between the teminal and cron?

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to diagnose some shenanigans, where my python code (Lightning.py) executes in a terminal window with "sudo ./Lightning.py" but not withing my cron job.

I am rather new to linux and would welcome any assistance!

Here is the code for Lightning.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import wget
import os
from shutil import copyfile

if os.path.exists("prepy.txt"):
  os.remove("prepy.txt")
print('Beginning file download from Saratoga Weather with wget module')

url = 'http://saratoga-weather.org/USA-blitzortung/placefile.txt'
wget.download(url, '/home/user/Desktop/prepy.txt')

old_lightnings = ['0,1,2,', '0,1,3,','0,1,4,','0,1,5,','0,1,6,','0,1,7,','0,1,8,','0,1,9,']

with open('prepy.txt') as oldfile, open('lightning.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(old_lightning in line for old_lightning in old_lightnings):
            newfile.write(line)
copyfile('/home/user/Desktop/lightning.txt', '/home/user/Music/lightning.txt')
print('\nLightning.py has been run')
```

And here is the associated cron job. It was set at every minute so I could test it.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/user/Desktop/Lightning.py
```

I am currently testing this in Ubuntu 18.04.3.

The only thing that does happen is that whenever the cron runs, it creates a file "prepy(1).txt", but doesn't sort through and delete lines and save it as the correct output.

As an added bonus, here is a sample of the downloaded file from the script:

```
;Bliztortung USA Placefile for GRLevel3
; Placefile by Ken True, saratoga-weather.org
; Updated: Sun, 24 Nov 2019 08:15:01 PST
RefreshSeconds: 300
IconFile: 1,30,30,15,15,http://saratoga-weather.org/USA-blitzortung/lightningicons.png
Icon: 29.860824,-76.139117,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:15:53 PST
Icon: 35.379265,-71.096417,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:16:09 PST
Icon: 31.609272,-73.765092,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:16:13 PST
Icon: 31.885003,-73.709302,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:16:13 PST
Icon: 35.459427,-70.928328,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:17:28 PST
Icon: 35.552307,-71.060657,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:17:28 PST
Icon: 31.669056,-73.737014,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:19:35 PST
Icon: 31.669056,-73.737014,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:19:35 PST
Icon: 30.22179,-75.510468,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:19:45 PST
Icon: 29.831653,-76.047618,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:20:38 PST
Icon: 29.812147,-76.042173,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:20:38 PST
Icon: 30.149676,-75.405737,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:21:29 PST
Icon: 31.799604,-73.352328,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:23:57 PST
Icon: 31.831979,-73.345653,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:23:57 PST
Icon: 38.715605,-67.371949,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:26:28 PST
Icon: 38.671515,-67.335955,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:26:28 PST
Icon: 30.147951,-75.345644,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:26:51 PST
Icon: 31.878007,-73.527605,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:26:58 PST
Icon: 31.848858,-73.334373,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:26:59 PST
Icon: 29.562893,-76.483871,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:27:24 PST
Icon: 29.640704,-76.541928,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:27:24 PST
Icon: 34.266843,-71.379808,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:27:44 PST
Icon: 29.810437,-75.893204,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:28:00 PST
Icon: 29.878976,-75.931348,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:28:00 PST
Icon: 29.903286,-75.94225,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:28:00 PST
Icon: 18.400364,-105.684513,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:28:11 PST
Icon: 38.524655,-67.036093,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:28:52 PST
Icon: 29.469489,-76.511855,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:29:14 PST
Icon: 29.661606,-76.533699,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:29:14 PST
Icon: 29.661606,-76.533699,0,1,9,Blitzortung @ 06:29:14 PST
```

Additional Info:

Here is a simplified version of the .py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import wget
import os
from shutil import copyfile

if os.path.exists("prepy.txt"):
  os.remove("prepy.txt")

url = 'sample_url/file.txt'
wget.download(url, 'path1/prepy.txt')

bad_strings = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']

with open('prepy.txt') as oldfile, open('postpy.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_string in line for bad_string in bad_strings):
            newfile.write(line)
copyfile('/path1/postpy.txt', '/path2/postpy.txt')
```

The cron job was made by typing in

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and adding the above cron job at the end of the file and saving cron. This was also done with regular permissions, where rather than typing "sudo" in front of "crontab -e" the following was entered

```
crontab -e
```

This *should* mean that sudo isn't used to run the file.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly troublesome.  You have covered all the usual *cron* sensitivities (relative pathnames, stdin/stdout assumptions, etc.)   I am curious about why `env` is used (twice!) to run python.

Comment: It was included twice through the process of diagnosing some earlier issues and was left in. Thanks wallyk!

Comment: What if you remove one of the shebangs?

Comment: I don't know much about `cron`, but wonder if it's running the script with `sudo` privileges like you do in terminal?

Comment: No dice unfortunately Tim, I removed the second line that uses python2

Comment: martineau, it is being run under the sudo crontab -e subset, so this should be using sudo by default as far as I know?

Comment: you should use module `logging` to save some information in log file. You could also use `try/except` and save error message in log file. It would explain what is the problem.

Comment: I'd also expect `sudo` to cause problems. Don't blindly use it without first forming an understanding what problems it is supposed to fix. None of what I see suggests that elevated privileges are required. That said, please extract and provide a [mcve], including full instructions how you install that thing into the crontab (and implicitly which crontab that is). As new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Ulrich, should have the requested information included now! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the working directory is not /home/user/Desktop/ when the code runs in cron.  Add a line at the beginning of the code:
`os.chdir("/home/user/Desktop/")`

Comment: You're the best! Everything runs properly with this line in place!!